# How can I report a spammer?

Tags: feature-request

Today I've twice encountered some spammer or spambot named "StackBot" pasting parts of FAQ as answers. Of course flagging it etc quickly solved the problem, but I didn't find a way to report the user himself.

Shouldn't there be some report button in user profile?

Comment: How is this duplicate, I asked about spammers in general, not just this one.

Comment: Well, the answer there shows very exemplary, how it was and should be handled, doesn't it? Also you've been asking for that particular occurence.

Comment: Anytime you see spam, please flag as spam. That's the process to report spamming users.

Answer (score 8):

Just flag one of their posts as spam.

Even if it's just one post we investigate the account to see if they're just misguided or someone who needs to have their account destroyed.

Comment: yes, but that's reporting the post, not the user, amirite? Or it propagates to the user as whole?

Comment: @Mighty - since the post is _by_ the user, yes. It is attached to the user.

Comment: @MightyPork We are merely judgeing about posts and their contents and not particular users. If a user repeatedly posts invalid answers or question they will be banned anyway.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ so that's some kind of automated process?

Comment: @MightyPork No, it involves moderators, they'll have a deeper look if a question is flagged for attention. May be they have automated reports, to find users that left posts which are flagged for spamming frequently, but I don't think there's a really automated process.