# How to report users spamming in Documentation requests?

Tags: feature-request, documentation, spam

I came to notice Documentation is getting spammed by users.

[image: Notifications]

But there is only an option to *dismiss* a documentation request. Nothing to flag the request as spam, or I could not find anything in the user profile to report the user.

For example, see the profile of [szally](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7255049/szsally?tab=documentation&sort=topicrequests)

[image: SPAM in Documentation requests]

A similar incident happened two days before.

[image: Chineese SPAM in documentation tab]

I saw [this topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280189/how-can-i-report-a-spammer), but it says to report their *posts* as spam. There is no report option in documentation request other than to just dismiss the request!

[image: Documentation dismiss option]

Do we need a feature to flag the Documentation request/spamming user to get their account suspended for a while?

Comment: Oh, lovely... Destroying the user doesn't delete the requests. I'll clean this up, but yeah... this needs some love.

Comment: @Shog9 Another [user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7254988/user7254988) spammed in [JS documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/topic-requests/7475) in Chinese just after you cleaned up!

Comment: Oh, good grief... That user's been *suspended!* Apparently we forgot to check for that here.

Comment: @Shog9 Its non stoppable.. Now it has [16 new spam requests](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/topics?tab=requests) from different users :O Could you subscribe to JS Documentation and keep cleaning up? I don't want to spam here!

Comment: I'll clean it up until I have to sleep; will hand it off if it's still going by then.

Comment: "[Now and then, they sleep. One eye open. Like birds.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-team-and-what-do-they-do/99341#99341)"

Comment: The simplified Chinese text spams in JS Docs keep hurting my eyes for this moment... Neither I know the reason nor meaning of them, I suggest that Docs should have auto filtering against non-English texts (as Docs contents written in English).

Comment: Is it kind of not ordered pentesting?

Comment: @xenteros nop, this translate to `Do G#u#i#z#h#o#u University [a bunch of totally useless crap...]`. When googling this you end up with lot of results, but quite some are disturbing even in the URL, so it's probably a fake university. PS I added # to prevent indexing.

Comment: @Shog9 Would it be possible to hard-delete these? They’re still on the site, under “dismissed.”

Comment: @Shog9 Now my notification shows there are 110 Chinese spam in JS Documentation requests! Oh, wait. There is 685 requests in JS documentation..

Comment: Awwwww... shit.

Comment: ...and people ask why Documentation still needs a lot of work...

Comment: 815 spam request in JS docs. Yer spam filters be in need of some tweakin'.

Comment: *grabs popcorn*

Comment: is it any help if we dismiss some of those manually?

Comment: also: wow, they seem to be generating false users quite fastly. all of them seem to have random generated names.

Comment: Just hop into [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) when you see those popup again.

Comment: As a quick update on this: they're still coming in on a regular basis. Adam made changes to block suspended users and to hide requests from deleted users... So as a temporary solution, I have a script that'll dismiss and destroy the author of any topic requests where the title contains more than a nominal amount of CJK characters. It runs every 3 minutes, and appears to be keeping up with the flood. We'll try & get a more robust solution in place later. Needless to say, testing this by posting requests containing CJK characters would be a very bad idea.

Comment: @Shog9 Just saw this post and checked the JS tag. There are still 2 spam requests there: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/topics?tab=requests

Comment: @Shog9 The 3 minute process doesn't seem to be picking all the spam up. I waited a few more min (you can see the time difference between my last comment) and now, not only are the 2 original spam request still there, a new third one popped up.

Comment: Yep - got logged out, @Tot. Should be working now.

Comment: @Shog9 Yup, all gone.

Comment: Here's another one: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339473/please-introduce-threshold-to-post-documentation-requests

Comment: [Here's another two](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/topics?tab=requests): [1](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/topic-requests/23104), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/topic-requests/23103)

Comment: Happening again with a few users: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7350712/lz1xbm) [two](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7350692/8kuoyn) [three](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7350730/cao3g1)...

Comment: @Shog your script seems to have stopped again. Docs is full of spam again.

Comment: @Shog9 What is the best way that normal SO users can help fight spammers? Right now I'm rejecting all the spam requests I see, but I'm not sure if that helps in the long run or not.

Comment: It doesn't hurt. I have a script running to delete them, but you can ping me if you notice a large number hanging around for more than, say, 5 minutes - chances are, my script fell over & I need to poke it. @The_Grits

Comment: Someone needs to be poked, but I'm not sure it's the script. Surely there is a better way of preventing these submissions from ever getting through, as opposed to dealing with them ex post facto?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not sure about how they organize accounts, since @shog9 hasn't posted stats already. :P Maybe they have all different Ips, maybe not... Hopefuly it is not a Distributed Denial of Stackoverflow Qualtiy (DDoSQ).

There can hardly be a person, who create an account for every (few) posting(s) and change IP.

To make this spam stop, why not introduce some Captcha check?

[image: Captcha]

Show captcha if anonymous (by IP) or `< 1000 rep`:

- 2 requests in 15 Minutes
- 3 requests in 60 Minutes

Show captcha if `> 1000 rep` and `< 10.000 rep`

- 10 requests in 60 Minutes

Addionaly we need an option to report some request as spam, so the community is able to ban temporaly a User (or a moderator permanent).

With this purposes (Captcha, and report spam) we should be able to handle it as a community. No need to wake up [one of our moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-team-and-what-do-they-do/99341#99341) ;)

Comment: Or, we could introduce a barrier of 10 rep to propose or request a topic on documentation, as well as a filter to reject anything that is primarily non-english characters. As there are multiple different users, presumably posting from different IP's, I don't think that flagging as spam is really going to help anything at this point

Comment: @TinyGiant:  10 rep is a bit low.  How about instead either 150 reputation for a new tag, or 10 points in a well-established tag for existing documentation examples?

Comment: Imho a rep cap would be fine, if nothing other helps. But a captcha is more forgiving in my opinion. Nobody is locked out by a captcha (A modern captcha also supports blind/deaf people). Some people who want to help by contribution could be locked out by a rep cap. (Assuming we fight against bots/not humans)

Comment: @Makato i figured 10 rep because that is the same limitation for protected questions. It filters out brand new accounts, meaning that the account creation couldnt be automated. It is relatively trivial for real humans to get 10 rep, so you wouldnt be filtering out those who have no interest in Q&A that are coming here solely to participate in docs. At this point i dont think SO (the company) would be willing to institute a 150 rep minimum. cc ChristianGollhardt

Comment: It comes in [waves](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5585486#5585486) and Docs isn't yet on [SpamRam](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5585309#5585309). I guess that gets priority now ...

Comment: Google's new invisible recaptcha could come in handy...

Comment: I'd guess the correct spelling would be "Distributed Denial of Stack Overflow Qualtiy (DDoSOQ)", though maybe it needs a hyphen. ;-)